# Why is it platform 9 3/4?

Tags: harry-potter

J.K. Rowling could have chosen any nonnegative integers {n,p,q} for {p,q} being relatively prime, p<q and q not equaling 0, for platform n p/q (she could have technically chosen a nonnegative irrational number, but let's forget that idea for now). So why did she choose n=9, p=3, and q=4?

I have no ideas.

Comment: I figure it's the same reason the Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles get their pizza delivered to 122 ⅛ᵗʰ.  Because it's funny.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman - Yes. The answer to most HP question is "because whimsy"

Comment: I always figured 1/4 would be hidden on the left of the wall they walk through, 2/4 (1/2) nonexistent because it would be on the divider, and 3/4 hidden to the right of the divider.

Comment: Because 3+4 = 7 

Answer (score 40, accepted):

She 'liked it'.

> "In choosing the number of the concealed platform that would take
> young witches and wizards to boarding school, I decided that it would
> have to be a number between those of the Muggle platforms - therefore,
> it was clearly a fraction.
>
> **The number nine and three-quarters presented itself without much
> conscious thought, and I liked it so much that I took it at once. It
> is the 'three-quarters' that makes it, of course."**
>
> <sub><sup>[Platform Nine and Three-Quarters By J.K. Rowling](https://www.wizardingworld.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/platform-nine-and-three-quarters)</sup></sub>

Comment: A comment discussion about the meaning of "fraction" has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124267/discussion-on-answer-by-valorum-why-is-it-platform-9-3-4) - please feel free to continue there.

Answer (score 3):

Aside from the "It flowed nicely and JK Rowling liked the sound of it" explanation which Valorum shared.

If you have platform 9 and platform 10 and you go through the barrier between the two.
There is logically a train track on *both sides* of the concealed platform

Adjacent to platform 9 3/4 is therefore a platform 9 1/4 which we never see used.

The entrance to the platform is in the middle where a hypothetical 9 1/2 would be located. So logically 9 3/4 is the platform on the Platform 10 side of the hidden area.

The name makes complete internal sense to me!

Comment: Except you walk straight through, not turn left or right in the wall to get to platform 9 3/4 or 9 1/4

Comment: Sure, or 9 and 10 could be facing each other. Or in different parts of the station entirely. I'm not sure that it *logically* follows that they're back-to-back.

Comment: Platform 9 and 10 at Kings Cross are separated by lines 9 and 10 rather than a wall. https://www.nationalrail.co.uk/stations-and-destinations/stations-made-easy/london-kings-cross-accessible-routes?routeId=142319

Comment: And originally based on Euston https://www.historic-uk.com/HistoryMagazine/DestinationsUK/Harry-Potter-Platform-9-Three-Quarters/

Comment: @Valorum It doesn't *logically* follow, the the simplest way to design a multi-track station is to start with platform 1, then two tracks, then platforms 2 and 3 facing, then two more tracks, etc. So the pairs of facing platforms would be 8--9 and 10--11, not 9--10.

Comment: @alephzero Several stations have tracks on the outside, e.g.: track-P1-P2-track-track-P3-P4-track. To further complicate things, several stations have a [Platform Zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_0).

Comment: @TripeHound including London King's Cross